# How do I track down slow MS Access Queries?

Tags: ms-access

I run a website for a non-profit, and the server crashed last week. I moved the code over to another server (hosted by Network Solutions). It has a Microsoft Access back end. Now, all the users are experiencing delays. I think it might be because certain queries need to be optimized (?). Is there a way to figure out which queries might be slow? (the website has ~150 pages)

Here's a very specific example. On the old server, this query was super fast:

```
SELECT      ACCNo, clubid, First_Name, Last_Name, State 
FROM        tblAccOne 
WHERE       clubid > 0 (GR_L+GR_ClubPts+GR_VisitorPts+GR_CurRegPts+GR_CurNatPts+GR_TransPts) >= 6000 AND 
            PlatinumAward = False 
ORDER BY    last_name, first_name
```

However, it runs like a DOG on the new server until I remove "clubid > 0" at which point it works great. Goes from taking 30 seconds to less than one sec.

Comment: Can be anything so you would've to do some root cause analysis first. Apart from that, MS Access backend over the Internet can be notoriously slow. As in, migrate to a decent database.

Comment: I agree that is the long-term solution, but I don't have time to port it now. It worked fine on the old server, so why would it not work on this one? What's potentially different that would affect query performance?

Comment: Might be your host. Bit of a puzzle and sorry to say but your question is beyond the goal of this forum.

Comment: What's the goal of the forum? I updated with a specific example.

Comment: "Is your question about programming?
We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
Provide details. Share your research."

Comment: The sole fact that it seems that a query is running slower now does not necessarily mean that it's due to the query. It might be due to a different server configuration, it might be due to.. well, there can be lots of reasons.Maybe your host can do some traffic speed analysis, that's what I'd start investigating first (as in, what changed...)

Comment: @PaulGregson Although many SQL and Access related issues are indeed perfect for Stack Overflow especially when they deal more with SQL, VBA code and general programming concepts, question regarding server performance are perhaps better for the Stack Exchange [Database Administrator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) forum.  Sometimes there's a fine line in what the communities deems appropriate.

Comment: Since Access is a shared-file database, the "server" can often refer to the file server where the database file actually resides.  But for online hosting, a "server" refers to the server running the network services.  It is possible for both to be one and the same, but esp. with Access we should not assume either.  Now to the point:  What do you mean precisely by "old" and "new" server - file server, network server or both?

Comment: Continuing on Rene's thread... What version of Microsoft Access Database Engine was running on the old and new server?  Is the server full maintained by your service provider?  Or is it running on virtual server that you manage?

Comment: Your example query is invalid. Please fix it.

Comment: @Rene. The access backend is NOT over the internet. The web server is in fact pulling the data from the file - no network is involved. The web clients don't pull data to the workstations over the network. So you confusing the difference between a desktop client program and that of a web server. They are MASSIVE different in how they work. No network stack is required when the web code pulls the access file data. In fact it is a "in-process" direct data read and this type of process can be up to 50% faster then using SQL server since you have to pull data from SQL server though a network stack

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal  Point taken that Access provides no native web/cloud services, but... There is likely an internal network on the server side, and the Access file may reside on a network server different than the web server. Also, "stack" can simply refer to the general collection of software making up any server solution, so there must certainly be some software layer that provides database services... even if it is in-process. An Access database becomes the effective back end as soon as other services provide data from the Access file. Not clear how the previous comments are not applicable.

Comment: Comments don’t apply since we have near 99% chance that no network is involved with the web server simply opening and reading that Access database. So if no network is involved, then comments about JET/ACE being slow over a network don’t apply, do they? The simple matter is little benefit exists by using a ACE/JET back end. Access is a developer tool and you can choose the database engine such as JET/ACE or something else. So in effect to be really clear, Access is not be used here – but only the default database engine that Access uses. So Access is not being used here - but JET or ACE is.

Answer (score 0):

So Access is a front end Windows app - and really isn't even a candidate to serve as a back end db.  You would go to SQL Server to be behind a web server.

But in any case the syntax that you write where I see: WHERE clubid > 0 
immediately after needs to be AND / OR 
before
(GR_L+GR_ClubPts+GR_VisitorPts............